# Range proof for ElGamal ciphertext

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, elgamal-encryption

Alice has an ElGamal public key $y=g^x$. Bob encrypts a value $g^b$ based on Alice's Elgamal public key and he ends up with a ciphertext $(g^by^r, g^r)$. Can Bob prove that the value $b$  is in some range without revealing it or do you need to be the "owner" of the ElGamal secret key $x$ to create such proofs?

If $g^b$ is confusing then ignore it and consider a value $b$, I just need to know if I can create a range proof without knowing the $x$.

Comment: Hi! I answered variants of this questions several time on this website, see for example [this thread](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/53745/is-it-possible-to-create-a-zero-knowledge-proof-that-a-number-is-more-than-zero/53762#53762). If this does not answer your question, could you specify where you are stuck?

Comment: @GeoffroyCouteau Hello,I was more spefic in a comment on the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

If your method of mapping your value $b$ to a group element is $g^b$, then creating a range proof for an El Gamal encryption is exactly the same as creating a range proof for a Pedersen commitment.

With El Gamal, you have $g^by^r$ where $b$ is the value, $r$ is the sender's ephemeral private key, and $y$ is the recipient public key.

Interpreted as a Pedersen commitment, you have $g^by^r$ where $b$ is the value, $r$ is the blinding factor, and $y$ is the alternative base point for which the discrete log w.r.t. $g$ (i.e. $x$) is unknowable to the committer/sender.

Note that since the recipient knows $x$, they can forge range proofs.

Details of how to create a simple range proof are [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/98759/43864).

Comment: So only the recipient who knows $x$ can forge a range proof for $b$ in $g^{b}y^{r}$?If for example I encrypt a value $b$ based on someone else's $y$ which of course I dont know the $x$ can I generate a range proof for $g^b$?

Comment: Only someone that knows $x$ can forge it, and yes you can generate a range proof without knowing $x$.